# monodevelop-6.0 make failed ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to install Monodevelop 6 on Ubuntu 16.04. And I don't want to install/run it using flatpak.

I'm following steps mentioned under ***Building from Tarballs*** given on [Monodevelop documentation](http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/) page. I've downloaded version **monodevelop-6.0.0.4761.tar.bz2** from [this download link](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/monodevelop/) and extracted it using archive manager directly.

The *configure* command is running successfully without any errors.
But the ***make*** command is failing with blow error:

```
Making all in external
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pratik/Downloads/monodevelop-6.0/external'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pratik/Downloads/monodevelop-6.0/external'
Making all in .
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pratik/Downloads/monodevelop-6.0'
touch vcrevision
mono .nuget/NuGet.exe restore
Cannot open assembly '.nuget/NuGet.exe': No such file or directory.
Makefile:1110: recipe for target 'restore-packages' failed
make[1]: *** [restore-packages] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pratik/Downloads/monodevelop-6.0'
Makefile:646: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a bug, don't use stackoverflow for bugs, please use http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: @knocte I didn't know it's a bug. I thought I was doing something wrong. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: No problem. Whenever you have submitted it, please post the URL of the bug here.

Comment: @knocte, here is the bug created in Bugzilla https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44889

Comment: why did you make it confidential?

Comment: Any idea how can I make changes? I am not able to edit it.

Comment: please make it non-confidential

Comment: @knocte how? I can't find a way to edit it.

Comment: @knocte, can you please help me with https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45127?

Comment: @knocte, I know I am bothering you a lot... but there is one more issue. Can you please take a look at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45520?

Comment: not sure how to fix that, but I know a workaround; if you want more details, find me on irc://irc.gnome.org/monodevelop (and from now on if you want to ping me, do it with IRC, not stackoverflow)